# Geopandas with Sublime & IDLE (Python)

Tags: python, geopandas

I get an error when I try to run my python script in Sublime and Python's IDLE. However I can run the same script in Command Prompt with no problem.

I installed all the modules.whl locally.

MyScript:

```
import geopandas
file = r'C:\WORK\testshape.shp'
geopandas.read_file(file)
print(file)
```

Error: Sublime and Python's IDLE

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'read_file' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: `I installed all the modules.whl locally.` You're not using a tool like pip to automatically manage dependencies?

Comment: i install it with 'pip install shapely-2.0.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl' the workstation I using does not have internet.

Comment: Do you have a module named geopandas.py in the directory? If you do, you won’t be able to import the package geopandas, so I’d rename it

Comment: Thank Michael. By changing the file name to something other then 'geopandas.py' have solve the problem.